# Android Floating Point and Negative Numbers Validation

Tags: android, regex

```
public void updateDisplay(View v)
{
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            tempNumber.setText(tempNumber.getText().toString() + ((Button) view).getText());
        }
    });

    tempNumber.setText( tempNumber.getText().toString() + ((Button) v).getText() );
}


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:onClick="updateDisplay"
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="@drawable/button_tx_color"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:onClick="updateDisplay"
        android:text="2"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="@drawable/button_tx_color"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:onClick="updateDisplay"
        android:text="3"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="@drawable/button_tx_color"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:onClick="updateDisplay"
        android:text="4"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="@drawable/button_tx_color"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="updateDisplay"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:text="5"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="@drawable/button_tx_color"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="updateDisplay"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:text="6"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="@drawable/button_tx_color"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="updateDisplay"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:padding="0sp"
        android:text="7"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="@drawable/button_tx_color"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="updateDisplay"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:text="8"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="@drawable/button_tx_color"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="updateDisplay"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:text="9"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="@drawable/button_tx_color"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button0"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="updateDisplay"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="@drawable/button_tx_color"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonDot"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="updateDisplay"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:text="."
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="@drawable/button_tx_color"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonM"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="updateDisplay"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:text="-"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="@drawable/button_tx_color"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
```

I have small peace of code, that updates and creates numbers on button click.
Everything works fine, but i want to make some validation of floating point and negative numbers.

Error:
12.343.325.4

Correct:
12.343 (second dot must not be written)

Error
12-324-45

Correct
-1234

tempNumber is a TextView, where i display result, nothing more.

Comment: Have a look at NumberFormat: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html - You can set the locale for your number style there, when you parse a number you get the result back, or null if something went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood what you are asking as it seems to be as easy as adding a little more code in the onClick method to prevent wrong values. Something like:

```
new View.OnClickListener() {

    private boolean dotPresent;

    public void onClick(View view) {
        String buttonText = ((Button)view).getText().toString();
        boolean isDot = buttonText.equals(".");
        boolean isSign = buttonText.equals("-");
        int currentLength = tempNumber.getText().length();

        if (isSign && currentLength != 0) return;
        if (isDot && dotPresent) return;

        tempNumber.setText(tempNumber.getText().toString() + buttonText);

        if (isDot) dotPresent = true;
    }
}
```

The previous class should be created only once and assigned to each button using setOnClickListener().

By the way, another possibility is considering using a normal EditText providing as inputType TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL | TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED. Then the soft keyboard should be presenting the user a numeric keyboard and the filters to prevent wrong values are present as well. More info in the Android documentation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL